# Installing mongodb in mac

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb on my system and following these steps(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) in doing so. I have installed Homebrew and MacPorts and have installed the mongodb using both Homebrew and MacPorts. But when i type mongod:

I get this:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6381 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Cs-MacBook-Pro.local
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.7, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin Cs-MacBook-Pro.local 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 dbexit: 
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Sep  9 20:58:35 dbexit: really exiting now
```

When i type mongo, i get this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: test
Sun Sep  9 20:58:39 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

Need some help on this...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a folder `/data/db/` in `/`. This is where MongoDB stores all its data. Then make sure it’s readable and writable by MongoDB using `chown` or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> in the Finder.

Comment: what name should i give it? and do i need to add it to the bash profile or something?

Comment: Just create the directory `/data/db` in `/` and make it readable and writable. That’s all.

Comment: how do u do the chown? can explain a little more?

Comment: is it something like this: sudo chown 777 db -r?

Comment: `sudo chown -R lakesh /data/db`

Answer (score 8):

I hate to add another answer because the current answer works, but I can't comment that answer so..

You can create the required data directory and give it the same permissions as the user you are logged into OS X as using the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Then you can fire up mongod using

```
./path/to/mongod
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers did not have the data directory for me (Mac OS Mavericks, Mongo (2.4.x)

The mongo data directory in Mac OS is located

```
/usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are surely good enough but I would also like to give a tip here.

What I would do is:

Download the respective binaries from mongodb site's download section.
Unarchive it in some folder, like /opt/mongo
Then add the path to the $PATH variable by adding the below line in .bashrc file `PATH="$PATH:/opt/mongo/bin"`

Now you can fire up mongod or mongo or mongoexport etc. from command line just like any other command.

Answer (score 2):

I spent quite a while trying to figure out how to install MongoDB and Mongoose. My problem with the new macOS Catalina update, the folder `/data/db` is read-only, you cannot modify it, so you have to store your database files somewhere else.  I had to go through the [MongoDB Installation Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/), which is summarized below.


**1. To install xcode, run in your macOS Terminal:**

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

**2. To install `brew` use the official [Homebrew Installation Instructions](https://brew.sh/#install).**

**3. To tap the [MongoDB Homebrew Tap](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew), run in your macOS Terminal:**

```
$ brew tap mongodb/brew
```

**4. To update Homebrew and all existing formulae:**

```
$ brew update
```

**5. To install MongoDB:**

```
$ brew install mongodb-community@5.0
```

---

**To start MongoDB, run:**

```
$ brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

**To stop MongoDB, run:**

```
$ brew services stop mongodb-community@5.0
```

**To verify that MongoDB is running:**

```
$ brew services list
```

See [How to Start MongoDB on Mac](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/start-mongodb-mac-how-to-start-mongodb-on-a-mac-438) for more help.

---

**To check where your database files are being stored run:**

```
$ sudo lsof -p `ps aux | grep mongodb | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 2` | grep REG
```

When I ran this command it showed that my files are being stored in a hidden file in my harddrive, Macintosh HD. In Finder you can push `SHFT + CMD + .` to show hidden files. If this command returns file names with a folder called mongodb, then you are good to go.

**If your files are still read-only, you can try to overwrite the default storage path with:**

```
$ mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

---

**To verify your MongoDB version:**

```
$ mongod --version
```

Comment: for zsh terminal (MAC)
Open up your .zshrc file with any text-editor

Add this line to the file:

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin:${PATH}"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695241/zsh-command-not-found-mongo . This costed me 2 hour thus adding for future explorer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method:

If you don’t like the default /data/db folder, just specify an alternate path with --dbpath

```
$ mongod --dbpath /any-directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is step which help you to install mongodb on your mac.

1.Download mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.6.tgz from server.

https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production

2.Open terminal.

3.Extract that folder

$ tar xvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.6.tgz

4.Go to that folder

$ cd mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.6

5.$ cd bin

6. Now goes to root level & enter password

   $ sudo bash
7. Then create data folder

## whoami

root

## mkdir -p /data/db

## chmod 777 /data/db

## ls -l /data/db

## ls -ld /data/db

drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  68 Apr 28 15:04 /data/db

8. Then exit that root

## exit

9. So now you are in bin folder again, So execute this command

   $ ./mongod

So, It will waiting for connection.

10. Now you can open 2nd new terminal, Go to bin folder

$ cd mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.6

$ cd bin

11. Then try to connect mongo

$ ./mongo

12. It will connect your DB, So you can insert data

> db.names.insert({'name':'piyush'})

Also, Retrive it by

> db.names.find()

https://piyushkachariya111.wordpress.com/2016/04/28/installing-mongodb-on-a-mac/

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue while running the mongodb server.

Process 1: Run the `activity monitor` and find for the mongodb instance and kill the process and run the command again.

or

Process 2 : Find the \data\db\ `data-directory\mongod.lock` file, and delete it and run the command

```
mongod --repair
```

After that you`ll see the information log with the following message

```
shutdown: removing fs lock...
```

Now run the `mongodb` command.

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Manual Method to install MongoDB in MAC

1.Download mongodb "mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.5.tgz" file

2.Extract it using the command

```
$ tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.5.tgz
```

3.Create a directory and copy the extracted contents to that

```
$ mkdir mongodb
$ cp -R -n mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.5.tgz/ mongodb
```

4.Create a file in home directory named .bash_profile and add the bin path to the same as shown below

```
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
```

5.Create directory data/db in any root location and add permission to the loggedin user using chown

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db 
$ whoami
  LoggedInUser
$ sudo chown  LoggedInUser /data/db
```

If we are using different dbpath instead of /data/db (Developer need to add this each time while execution if we are using different location)

```
mongod --dbpath <path to data directory>
```

6.Close and open terminal and verify the working using mongod

```
$ mongod
```

7.Connect to mongo using mongo command

```
$ mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install mongoDB on your local machine using the following steps:

1. Go to the official website of mongoDB
   [MongoDB download center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community)
   [image]
2. Download the community or enterprise server but make sure to select your operating system for mac it's macOS x64
3. After downloading the package put it in a folder of your choice preferably in home directory but you can put it in a folder on your desktop but you should not move it if you move it after setting the path you need to change the path again in the following steps I have the downloaded folder in my home directory if you have it somewhere else you need to change the path accordingly
4. Open your terminal make sure it's bash 
   [image]
5. In this step you need to tell your machine where it can find the MongoDB commands you have downloaded to do that you need to give the path to your downloaded MongoDB folder it's easy just run in your terminal `sudo nano /etc/paths` the contents of your paths should appear go to the folder containing your MongoDB folder and right click on this MongoDB folder and click on copy to copy the path to this folder then go to the terminal and paste the copied path in the paths file and add at the end of it /bin because bin will contain all MongoDB shell commands you will be using then press control + x then y(this means you are telling the terminal save my file) to save the changes then enter to quit nano.
   [image]
6. close your terminal and reopen it then run mongo --nodb this should start your MongoDB shell and you will have successfully installed MongoDB
   [image]
7. To exit the MongoDB shell write exit and press enter