# zsh: command not found: mongo

Tags: mongodb, macos

I'm following the official instructions found here (on Mac OS Big Sur): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

When attempting to run `mongo`, I receive:

`zsh: command not found: mongo`

I then check if MongoDB is running by running:

`brew services start mongodb-community@4.4`

I then receive:

`Service mongodb-community@4.4 already started, use brew services restart mongodb-community@4.4 to restart`

Because of this, I know MongoDB is running. What gives? I followed the official instructions from MongoDB's website.

Comment: mongo vs mongod. missed the "D"

Comment: mongod is for starting the daemon. MongoDB is already running. I am attempting to access the shell, thus mongo.

Regardless, mongod has the same response:
`zsh: command not found: mongod`
@MarekH

Comment: The binary for the shell is `mongosh` (as documented in the link you posted). Also check, if the binary folder of brew is part of the PATH variable.

Comment: On intel macs this path should work "/usr/local/bin/mongosh", "/usr/local/bin/mongod", "/usr/local/bin/mongo". Seems there were some warnings during instal which you have missed

Comment: There is nothing mongo related in /usr/local/bin @MarekH I am on the M1 architecture if that makes a difference

Comment: Reinstall and read warnings (during install). Brew also prints where binary was installed/placed

Answer (score 15):

I did the above procedures and it still didn't work. But use this, then it worked!

brew install mongodb-community-shell

Comment: This worked for me, I had installed mongodb, it had the bin folders, but no client. Such a simple thing to overlook. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried Hanry's procedures without success. Xinyi's answer here worked with and without Hanry's changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

For **Apple M1 Processor**:

If you install `mongodb` through `Homebrew`, follow the steps below:

1. Open up your `Terminal`
2. Type `brew list` to check the formulae of the installed `mongodb`

```
==> Formulae 
mongodb-community@4.4   mongodb-dxxx... 

==> Casks
xxxxx
```

- In my case, it is `mongodb-community@4.4`.

3. In the terminal, type `brew list mongodb-community@4.4` to get the directory of the `mongodb` installed in your machine.

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin/install_compass
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin/mongo
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin/mongod
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin/mongos
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.4.plist
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/MPL-2
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

4. Copy the bin path of your mongodb: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin`
5. Open up your `.zshrc` file with any text-editor
6. Add this line to the file:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.4/4.4.13/bin:${PATH}"
```

7. Try `mongo --version` in your terminal, if you see similar output like shown below, you are good to go.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.13
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.13",
    "gitVersion": "df25-----------b9246",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for Macbook Pro - Big Sur (Intel)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This is the best solution for using ZSH (instead of Bash) and typing `mongod --version` (not sure if the OP had a typo but I had the same problem with the correct spelling). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with this command running on terminal but only path I added is diffrent
Steps:

1. `brew list mongodb-community@4.0.`  (run this first)
2. then copied `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.0/4.0.28/bin.`  this path
3. and executed:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community@4.0/4.0.28/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```
4. Then I have checked by openning .zshrc file is my path has set on not by executing - `nano .zshrc     command`

Answer (score 0):

I did the above procedures and it still didn't work. But I restarted my terminal using $exec bash -l and it works!